# Unlocking/Using smash balls in SSF2 beta

Tags: super-smash-flash-2

When searching through the item switch on Super Smash Flash, I was suprised when there was no option to turn on smash balls. I went to training mode to see if I can spawn them there, but to my suprise, they weren't there. I have not been able to locate another source on this topic, so I have to ask: where are the smash balls?

Comment: How does a question get 37,000 views and no upvotes? lol

Answer (score 3):

As the other (deleted) answer said, they are gone temporarily during a big update.  It seems to be so that they can have the update available while still working on some features.

> Rather than keep you waiting until these things are fixed, please note that some minor features will remain disabled temporarily including:
>
> - Final Smashes
> - Gamepad support in the Browser version
> - Online Arena Mode (Sandbag Soccer)
> - Peril Roulette in Classic Mode
> - Character-Specific Break the Targets
> - ‘Trades’ between opposing attacks
> - Accessorized costumes
> - Misc. stage hazards (Green Hill Zone, etc.)
>
> We promise to send out auto-updates to enable these features as soon as we get the issues ironed out.

Source: https://www.mcleodgaming.com/news

TBH I'm not sure why the other answer was deleted besides making it unclear that they were quoting the site.